# ActiveRecord::Base#all, where, joins etc method executes after ensure block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to execute `Model.all` in a begin-ensure block. But ensure block code executes before query Like,

```
def some_method
   puts "start"
   Model.all
ensure
   puts "ensure"
end
```

Expected output:

```
start
SELECT "models".* FROM "models";
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Model id:1 ..>,...]>
ensure
```

Actual output:

```
start
ensure
SELECT "models".* FROM "models";
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Model id:1 ..>,...]>
```

Comment: Can you please try `Model.all.load` instead?

Comment: There is a good blog post about `ensure` behaviour:  http://blog.leshill.org/blog/2009/11/17/ensure-with-explicit-return.html

Comment: `all` just generates a scope. It does not execute the query until acted upon. This allows for the query chains like `all.where(...).order(...).limit(...).where(...)` as @spickermann pointed out you can force it to `load` (execute the query) to get you anticipated result